# Particle energy in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity

Assume that a particle is moving with four-velocity $u^\mu$ through a spacetime with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ ($-+++$ signature).

Let us also assume that there exists a time-like vector field $t^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$.

Is it generally true that the energy $E$ of a particle is given by the following expression:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E &=& -mt_\mu u^\mu\\
&=& -mg_{\mu\nu} t^\nu u^\mu\\
&=& -mg_{00}u^0\\
&=& -mg_{00}\frac{dt}{d\tau}?
\end{eqnarray*}

In the special case that $t^\mu$ is a Killing vector and $u^\mu$ is tangent to a geodesic then $E$ is a constant of motion of the particle. But the energy of a particle need not remain constant in the general case - is that true?

If $E=-mt_\mu u^\mu$ is indeed the particle mass/energy then does it act as a source of spacetime curvature given that it depends on the $00$-component of the spacetime metric ifself? I suppose that is not a problem.

Answer (score 10):

Yes that is true and the verification is a routine calculation. In SR the energy of a particle with 4-momentum $p^{\mu}$ is simply $E = p^0$ relative to some inertial frame $\mathcal{O}$.

Let's say an observer at rest in $\mathcal{O}$ has a 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$. Then in the coordinates of $\mathcal{O}$ we simply have $u^{\mu} = (1,0,0,0)$ so we can write $E = -p^{\mu}u_{\mu}$, the negative sign coming from the Lorentzian signature. Now this is a Lorentz invariant expression so it must hold in all frames.

In particular, let's now go to curved space-time and consider a particle with 4-momentum $p^{\mu}$. Let's also consider an observer $\mathcal{O}$ (I'm using observer and frame interchangeably) with a local Lorentz frame $e_{\hat{\alpha}}$. We know that the metric in this frame is just $\eta_{\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta}}$ so, as long as we are working with calculations that involves taking *no* derivatives, we are effectively just doing SR. In other words the relation $E = -p^{\mu}u_{\mu}$ carries over unscathed.

As a quick aside, calculations involving taking only *one* derivative that are still equivalent to SR calculations require a freely falling coordinate system around an event.

Your question regarding Killing fields requires a little bit of care. Note that $u^{\mu}$ by itself can never in general be a Killing field except in flat space-time. This is because $u^{\mu}$ has to be normalized to proper time but the time-like Killing field $\xi^{\mu}$ will not be normalized as such. The conserved energy is actually $\mathcal{E} = -p^{\mu}\xi_{\mu}$, not $E = -p^{\mu}u_{\mu}$ even if $p^{\mu}$ is tangent to a geodesic and $u^{\mu} = \gamma \xi^{\mu}$.

In fact, for the latter we have $\frac{dE}{d\tau} = -p^{\mu}p^{\nu}\nabla_{(\mu}u_{\nu)}$ and in general $\nabla_{(\mu}u_{\nu)} \neq 0$. If $u^{\mu}$ is tangent to a Killing field then in general only $h^{\alpha}{}{}_{\mu}h^{\beta}{}{}_{\nu}\nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = 0$ i.e. the congruence is Born-rigid; here $h_{\mu\nu}$ is the 3-metric relative to the congruence.

The difference between $\mathcal{E}$ and $E$ is that the former is the energy of the particle as measured by an observer at spatial infinity whereas the latter is the energy as measured by a local observer. Even if we have a congruence of local observer that are stationary (follow the orbits of a time-like Killing field) $E$ will not be conserved along the particle worldline.

Roughly speaking, the reason for this is that, as mentioned earlier, $E$ is basically just the resultant of an SR (i.e. local) measurement. It doesn't know anything about the gravitational field in and of itself. Gravitational energy cannot be localized. $\mathcal{E}$ on the other hand is the resultant of a global measurement since it is measured at spatial infinity. Global measurements *do* know about the gravitational field.

Finally, in practice $E$ does not contribute to the space-time curvature as defined because it is the energy of a *test* particle. In principle it would of course contribute but then we get into the technical issues of the space-time geometry due to a point particle.

Comment: You do not need to care about the connection coefficients vanishing. A local Lorentz frame only requires the metric to be Minkowski. The connection coefficients vanishing is only required for the local inertial coordinates which is not necessary for the verification of the relation the OP seeks. A local Lorentz frame can always be introduced-this is a basic result of linear algebra.

Comment: Yes of course you can introduce a local Lorentz frame but this is no way implies you can just do SR. This is a very common misconception. If you fix a frame such that the metric is now $\eta_{ab}$ the basic variables are now functions of the basis components of the orthnormal frame. This is GR since the Riemann tensor is not zero! It depends on the basis vectors of the orthnormal frame!

Comment: Let me add to my above comment: in an orthnormal frame: you are correct that the metric is now locally that of Minkowski: $g(e_a,e_b) = \eta_{ab}$. But the key point is as follows: these basis vectors satisfy $[e_a,e_b] = \gamma^c_{ab} e_c$ , where the gamma functions are the commutation functions of the basis and the Riemann tensor is a function of these functions. So this is GR

Comment: The calculations in the local Lorentz frame are SR calculations so long as no derivatives are involved, as I have already mentioned. Obviously if you convert from the tetrad to the coordinate basis then the dependence on the space-time geometry will emerge but that doesn't change the fact that within the frame I am allowed to do SR within the noted limitations. It doesn't change the verification of $E = -p_{\mu}u^{\mu}$.

Comment: Yes, no derivatives means the commutation functions are zero. I just wanted to make sure the correct terminology is being used. A bit of a stickler here. !

Comment: This just seems to be semantics. What part of the argument in my answer is incorrect? It is a textbook statement that calculations in local Lorentz frames (or orthonormal tetrads, whichever you prefer) are just SR calculations.; the point is that calculations in local Lorentz frames don't know about space-time curvature.

Comment: My issue is this notion that you can just introduce a local Lorentz frame. It always seems like one misses the larger beauty of doing GR in a fully curved spacetime. Note that quantum field theory in curved spacetime is certainly not done by introducing a local Lorentz frame in the neighbourhood of each point. One has to assume that the metric is dynamical and not static in general.

Comment: I don't think personal preferences are valid reasons to downvote or debate. If you don't like using local Lorentz frames then that's cool but it's a ubiquitous tool in GR calculations both at the textbook and research level; it's a useful tool that makes calculations very easy.

Comment: Down vote? I didn't down vote your answer. Yes its ubiquitous amongst particle physicists who do GR, but not liked amongst GR folks who do GR, or mathematical physicists who do GR.

Comment: I apologize for assuming you downvoted (someone did) but I think it's best to agree to disagree since this really is a matter of personal preference. It might clutter up the comments here. I can only tell you that I work in a pretty well known theoretical GR group, have talked to a fair number of famous relativists, and have read enough papers to tell you that many relativists use local Lorentz frames in calculations simply because they are necessary in order to extract the physics. What mathematical physics working in GR do is, however, beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Yes.  I'm a mathematical physicist working in GR, so we're a bit different. I learned GR from Charles Dyer and George Ellis, so I guess we're a bit old school. :-)

Comment: That's fair haha :)

Answer (score 2):

No it's not: infact if you have a non-diagonal metric tensor it's not just about $g_{00}$. For example in Kerr space time you obtain $E/m=-g_{00}\dot{t} - g_{03}\dot{\phi}$.

Comment: Hi Alessandro Rovetta, welcome to PSE! This is a nice answer, but it would be much better if you were to include a reference. Where does your expression of $E/m$ come from? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry but I simply calculated using the definition ^^ In fact, considering that $\pmb{t}:= t^0 \pmb{e}_0 = \pmb{e}_0$ i obtain $E/m = - g_{0 \nu} t^0 \dot{x}^\nu = - g_{0\nu}\dot{x}^\nu = - g_{00} \dot{x}^0 - g_{03}\dot{x}^3 = -g_{00}\dot{t} - g_{03}\dot{\phi}$

Comment: p.s. I used Kerr metric in Boyer–Lindquist coordinates.

Comment: After more than one year, I found a reference ^^: http://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/leonardo/bh/bhcap3.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1q1-T7P0rCo0_fef0GwOEXrkKUuj302Uf84oHibBki5gRXa3YJD_a2nnM page 43, chapter 3.2, formula 3.21.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, energy is that quantity that is conserved as a result of time invariance. So yes, in GR the energy of a particle is given by your formula (multiplied by the mass). It does act as a source of curvature; after all, the things we usually think of as producing gravity, like the Earth and the Sun, are themselves made out of particles.

Edit: Actually, there is a subtlety: the energy as defined by your formula is a scalar, but there is no reason to expect it to be. I would define the energy of a particle as the time component of $-m u_\mu$. In strange coordinate systems a time coordinate might not be easy to define: I'll leave that issue to someone more knowledgeable about the subject.

Comment: So is the particle energy $E=t_\mu u^\mu$ generally valid even if $t^\mu$ is not a Killing vector or $u^\mu$ is not tangent to a geodesic so that $E$ changes?

Comment: @John: well, there should be an $m$ in there, and a minus sign if you're in $(-+++)$ signature. At least to me, that is the only meaningful definition of energy; you could choose to call it something else, but I'm not sure what purpose that would serve.

Comment: Ok so I can take $E=-mg_{00}dt/d\tau$ to be the general expression for the energy of a particle?

Comment: @John: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: @Javier Note that in general curved spacetimes, one does not have any form of time invariance, so this discussion would not apply. See my comments below.

Answer (score 1):

One has to be ***very*** careful here. In General Relativity, there is no general definition of energy or particles.

The reason is as follows: 
The definition cited is based on the naive particle interpretation of quantum field theory. It is well understood that in the context of cosmological models and more general spacetimes, one simply does not have a time-translation symmetry because of a lack of timelike Killing vector field. Therefore, the very definition of particles is undefined for general curved spacetimes, and only defined in the context of general relativity for asymptotically flat spacetimes. The reason is that for the particle interpretation to work, one needs to be able to decompose the quantum field into positive and negative frequency parts, which in itself depends heavily on the presence of a such a time translation symmetry in either an asymptotically flat spacetime or a Minkowski spacetime.  The problem of course is that, our universe, or any spatially homogeneous and non-static universe, that is, one that does not contain a global timelike Killing vector field is necessarily \emph{not} asymptotically flat.

Namely, consider a spacetime $(\hat{M}, \hat{g}_{ab})$. Let this spacetime have the following three properties:

1. There exists a function $\omega \geq 0 \in C^3$, such that $g_{ab} = \omega^2 \hat{g}_{ab}$,
2. on the boundary $\omega = 0$, and $\omega_{,a}  \neq 0$,
3. Every null geodesic intersects the boundary in two points.

These spacetimes are called asymptotically simple. However, if we now associate the metric tensor, $g_{ab}$  with the Einstein field equations, the existence of these three conditions implies that the spacetime is asymptotically flat. It is only under these three conditions, for which one can in a meaningful way talk about ``particles'' or energy or energy of such particles!

Just a very important caveat that is often missed in such discussions nowadays. :-)

Answer (score -2):

> Assume that a particle is moving with four-velocity $u^\mu$ through a spacetime with metric...

Actually, there's a problem with that. A particle moves through space. Not through spacetime. Spacetime models space at all times. So it's static. You can plot worldlines in it to depict the motion through space over time, but the particle isn't actually moving up that worldline.

> But the energy of a particle need not remain constant in the general case - is that true?

No. The energy remains constant. Conservation of energy applies. You must know this, because you surely know that if you send a 511keV photon into a black hole, the black hole mass increases by 511keV/c². It doesn't increase by 512keV/c², or by a zillion tonnes. There is no magical mechanism by which the descending photon gains energy. Gravity is not a force in the Newtonian sense. The photon looks blueshifted because you and your clocks go slower when you're lower. It *looks* like it's gained energy, but it hasn't. Instead, you've lost it, check out the [mass deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation). The situation in special relativity isn't totally different. If you accelerate towards the source, the photons appear to be blueshifted. But they haven't changed one jot. Instead you have.

> If $E=-mt_\mu u^\mu$ is indeed the particle mass/energy then does it act as a source of spacetime curvature

Yes. This is how you know the particle's energy doesn't increase. The net gravitational field of two bodies doesn't increase as they fall towards one another.