# The energy of a photon and gravitational red shift

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-redshift

The general formula for gravitational red shift is given by:
$$ \newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} \f{\omega_r}{\omega_e} =\f{p_\nu(r)V^\nu(r)}{p_\mu(e)V^\mu(e)}$$
where $p_\nu(r)$ represents the 4-momentum of the photon at the receiver, $p_\mu(e)$ is its four momentum of the photon at the emitter, $V^\nu(r)$ and $V^\mu(e)$ represent the 4-velocities of the emitter an reviser respectively.

This formula holds because 
$$E(r)=p_\nu(r)V^\nu(r)$$
where $E(r)$ is the energy as measured by someone moving with the receiver (and analogous for the emitter). I can see that this equation hold true if both the emitter and receiver are in a locally inertial frame (i.e. free fall) since here the laws of special relativity must hold. However, I cannot see by what argument it is true for the receiver and emitter in arbitrary motion.  Thus what argument can be use?

(A source would be helpful)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists By M. P. Hobson, ‎G. P. Efstathiou and ‎A. N. Lasenby p221-224

Comment: Sorry, this question already has an answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194622/particle-energy-in-general-relativity.